# Appending a list to display in a text-field% in Racket

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, racket

I have a function that receives a list of strings, named "derivedSentences" that needs to be displayed in a text-field.

```
(for-each (lambda (singlesentence)
          (send derivationPanelTextField set-value singlesentence)
               ) derivedSentences)
```

However, as it is like this, each time it loops, it just replaces what was previously inside, so only the last string is shown. But I am trying to make it show step-by-step, so i would need to be constantly appending the strings with each iteration of the loop, but whatever I try doesn't work. It's either an error, or the text-field would show blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not query the text from the text-field, you still can accumulate the text in a string variable.

```
(let ((text ""))
  (for-each
   (lambda (singlesentence)
     (set! text (string-append text singlesentence))
     (send derivationPanelTextField set-value text))
   derivedSentences))
```